# Sha256 and abi.encode of number

Tags: hash, solidity-0.6.x

If I calculate the following in Solidity 0.6.3:

```
bytes memory secretSalt = "abc";
hashedSecret = sha256(abi.encodePacked(secretSalt))
```

I get the result "0xba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad" which matches what I get on two online SHA256 generators when I input "abc" (though, without the quotes, see [here](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html) and [here](https://xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator)).

But if I try

```
uint secretNumber = 5;
hashedSecret = sha256(abi.encodePacked(secretNumber));
```

The result is "0x96de8fc8c256fa1e1556d41af431cace7dca68707c78dd88c3acab8b17164c47" which does not match those online SHA256 generators. I tried various hex representations of 5 on the online SHA256 generators and still cannot get "0x96de..."

Any thoughts on how Solidity is transforming the number "uint 5", relative to these common SHA256 implementations?

Answer (score 1):

The type `uint` is 32 bytes in length, so uint(5) is stored as `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005` in hexadecimal.

In order to test this input you need a calculator that accepts hexadecimal input, many only accept text strings.

Comment: It's strange that those two online Sha256 generators handle the "abc" input correctly while I can't get them to work for unit(5) under various translations. Meanwhile, I went to https://www.liavaag.org/English/SHA-Generator/, and it works (it has a toggle for text or hex input).

Comment: @EricFalkenstein It works because "abc" is declared as string, so abi.encode returns their ascii representation (in hexadecimal "616263"). If you use a type of fixed length like uintNNN or bytesNN abi.encode will fill missing with 0 bytes.